# Can you host a bitbucket pipeline internally?

Tags: continuous-integration, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

We are currently using bitbucket cloud to host our grails-app repository. We want to set up some pipelines to do things like run unit tests and make sure the app compiles before being able to merge a branch to master.

I know this can pretty easily be done by letting them host the pipeline and committing a well written pipe file, however there is a problem standing that our app is very large, and even on brand new macbook pros takes 20 minutes to compile, on some older ones it can take 2 hours or more. Grails, thankfully, only compiles files that have changes in them from the last compilation. However, this can't be used on a bitbucket pipe that's working off a fresh pull of the app every time it runs.

My solution to this was wanting to set up a pipeline to run for us internally so that it can already have the app pulled, and just switch to the desired branch and run from there. This still might take time if switching between 2 very diverged branches, but it's better than compiling from fresh every time.

I can't seem to find any documentation on hosting a pipeline internally with bitbucket cloud, does anyone know if this is possible, and if so where there is documentation for it?

It would also be acceptable to find a solution to the long compilation problem itself with bitbucket hosted pipelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few weeks ago, self hosted runners was made available as a public beta. Here are the details: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-Pipelines-articles/Bitbucket-Pipelines-Runners-is-now-in-open-beta/ba-p/1691022

Additionally, if you're looking to retain some of your files from one build to the next to save doing the same work over and over again, have a look at caches: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-dependencies/ there are some built ones that you could use, but you can define your own custom ones as well. Essentially it's just a way of preserving the contents of a directory for a future build.